# Define Default Charset for htmlentities()

Tags: php, unicode, special-characters, character-encoding

I was wondering if there were any way to define the default encoding for `htmlentities()`. I have a big project going that uses `htmlentities` calls all over the place, and was wondering if there was a simple way to set it from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 as the default character encoding, using something simple like `ini_set()`. Or possibly with a separate [namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) declaration.

Failing that, I would not be opposed to renaming and overriding the `htmlentities` function to always use Unicode, but am reluctant to install anything as freaky (to me) as [PECL apd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php).

Comment: Why not just use htmlspecialchars? htmlentities converts far more than you need to for HTML, and due to the way Why not just use htmlspecialchars and UTF-8 works, none of the characters it converts will appear in the middle of a multi-byte UTF-8 character, meaning that, strictly speaking, it doesn't matter if it just assumes ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the manual page doesn't say anything about changing the default charset, I don't think there is a way to do that ; and I don't remember having ever seen anything about that.

I wouldn't use anything like apd either -- instead, I would probably :

- create my own function, that calls htmlentities with the right parameters
- and replace every call to htmlentities by a call to my new function *(this can probably be done automatically, using a few lines of scripts)*

Answer (score 0):

@Pascal MARTIN's solution is definitely correct, you can also use [`utf8-encode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

And [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The problem is not the charset the string is in, it's how htmlentities deals with it.